# What is this character? â\u0080\u0099

Tags: ruby, character-encoding

What is this character: â\u0080\u0099 ?

This should be an apostrophe or a single quote.

How can I convert it (using Ruby) to a simple, single quote '
or display it properly in a web page as a single quote?

Thanks

Comment: The answer is to be found in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972203/special-characters-in-r

Comment: Thanks.  I did read that post.  But it's still not clear to me how to display it as an apostrophe or a single quote to the user.  So either I have to do a regular expression search and replace? or some kind of character encoding conversion.

Answer (score 10):

It is a typographically correct apostrophe, more exactly RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK' (U+2019) (’), after some munging in incorrect character code conversions or interpretations. It seems to be an UTF-8 encoded form of that character (three bytes, 0xE2 0x80 0x99) incorrectly interpreted as ISO-8859-1 encoded data.

Comment: Thank you.  This post also helped me (especially post by phrogz) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572396/nokogiri-open-uri-and-unicode-characters

Comment: BTW, I fixed a file full of junk like this with the command `iconv -f utf8 -t iso-8859-1 < input`, which resulted in actually valid UTF-8 text (I basically performed the inverse of the initial incorrect munge). Just in case anyone else saw this and was trying to repair some text.